# rviz menu missing collision map topic

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rviz, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am running ros-diamonback on linux and having been going through the motion_planning_environment tutorials and but am struggling in seeing the visualization of collision maps in rviz as I cannot see it as a topic that I can enable and add. I know that I do have a collision map topic that is issued between the collision_map_self_occ node and the environment_server node. I have an intel graphics card and am aware that it is not that compatible with rviz...not sure if that's an issue here, but is there a work around for this?

Also, everytime I try to use the "mapping' plugin and the "articulation' plugin rviz instantaneously crashes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10688/rviz-menu-missing-collision-map-topic/) by [diannay](https://answers.ros.org/users/745/diannay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-21**:
Need more details. What display type are you adding in rviz that you expect to see topics for?  Have you either gotten a core dump, or otherwise have a stack trace from the crashes? Have you installed ros via deb packages, or from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just updated my diamondback debs and the collision map topic is working fine for me.  The CollisionMap type is contained in the mapping plugin, so the fact that you can't load that is why you can't add the marker type.  The graphics card issue could be part of it, or there could be something else non-standard about your setup - for instance, version incompatabilities between debs or code that you've built.  Posting the particular errors would help as well.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-30**:
It does sound like your graphics card is the issue.  The requirements for rviz are basically the same as Gazebos for graphics cards.  See http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/SystemRequirements for more details.

**Comment by [diannay](https://answers.ros.org/users/745/diannay/) on 2011-07-22**:
I'm not sure if version incompatabilities is an issue because visualization works when running on a different machine with nvidia graphics card. Sorry, I guess i should have mentioned that earlier.